# Transform a nested object using lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

Input:

```
const a =  {
            "8": [{
                "strategy": 123,
                "id": 1,
                "config": {
                    "global_dag_conf": {
                        "algo_v2_conf": {
                            "features_to_combine": [],
                            "segments": [],
                            "force_performance": false,
                            "min_bid": 0,
                            "max_bid": 13
                        }
                    }
                }
            }],
            "13": [{
                "strategy": 456,
                "id": 2,
                "config": {
                    "global_dag_conf": {
                        "algo_v2_conf": {
                            "ivr_measured": []
                        }
                    }
                }
            }]

        }
```

Output:

```
{
   "8": [
      {
         "global_dag_conf": {
            "algo_v2_conf": {
               "features_to_combine": [],
               "segments": [],
               "force_performance": false,
               "min_bid": 0,
               "max_bid": 13
            }
         },
         "algo_id": 1
      }
   ],
   "13": [
      {
         "global_dag_conf": {
            "algo_v2_conf": {
               "ivr_measured": []
            }
         },
         "algo_id": 2
      }
   ]
}
```

I tried below solution which works fine but need to know if is there any better way to do this using lodash and JS.

```
result = _.map(_.keys(addtionalAlgos), (algoType) => {
    addtionalAlgos[algoType] = _.map(addtionalAlgos[algoType], v => _.assign(v.config, { algo_id: v.id }));
    return addtionalAlgos;
  })[0]
```

Comment: What is the relation between input & output?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`_.mapValues()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#mapValues) to iterate the keys, and [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) with [object destructuring](http://%7B%228%22:[%7B%22strategy%22:123,%22id%22:1,%22config%22:%7B%22global_dag_conf%22:%7B%22algo_v2_conf%22:%7B%22features_to_combine%22:[],%22segments%22:[],%22force_performance%22:false,%22min_bid%22:0,%22max_bid%22:13%7D%7D%7D%7D],%2213%22:[%7B%22strategy%22:456,%22id%22:2,%22config%22:%7B%22global_dag_conf%22:%7B%22algo_v2_conf%22:%7B%22ivr_measured%22:[]%7D%7D%7D%7D]%7D) and [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_object_literals) to reformat the object:

```js
const data = {"8":[{"strategy":123,"id":1,"config":{"global_dag_conf":{"algo_v2_conf":{"features_to_combine":[],"segments":[],"force_performance":false,"min_bid":0,"max_bid":13}}}}],"13":[{"strategy":456,"id":2,"config":{"global_dag_conf":{"algo_v2_conf":{"ivr_measured":[]}}}}]}

const result = _.mapValues(data, 
  arr => arr.map(({ id: algo_id, config }) => 
    ({ algo_id, ...config })
))

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution without using lodash:

- Use [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to get an array of key-value pairs
- Create a new object by using [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) over the array
- Use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to create a new array of objects.
- Destructure each object to get `id` and `config`. [Spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) the `config` variable to remove one level of nesting

```js
const input = {"8":[{"strategy":123,"id":1,"config":{"global_dag_conf":{"algo_v2_conf":{"features_to_combine":[],"segments":[],"force_performance":false,"min_bid":0,"max_bid":13}}}}],"13":[{"strategy":456,"id":2,"config":{"global_dag_conf":{"algo_v2_conf":{"ivr_measured":[]}}}}]}

const output = 

Object.entries(input)
      .reduce((r, [key, value]) => {
          r[key] = value.map(({ id, config }) => ({ algo_id: id, ...config }));
          return r;
      }, {})
      
console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 1):

A pure Lodash solution using [mapValues](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#mapValues), [map](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#map) and [assign](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#assign) methods

```js
let data = {"8":[{"strategy":123,"id":1,"config":{"global_dag_conf":{"algo_v2_conf":{"features_to_combine":[],"segments":[],"force_performance":false,"min_bid":0,"max_bid":13}}}}],"13":[{"strategy":456,"id":2,"config":{"global_dag_conf":{"algo_v2_conf":{"ivr_measured":[]}}}}]};

let res = _.mapValues(data, arr => _.map(arr, obj => _.assign({
  'algo_id': obj.id,
  'global_dag_conf': obj.config.global_dag_conf
})));

console.log(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative without lodash.

The function `reduce` allows to generate an object which will be filled using the function `map` which transforms the original objects to the desired structure.

```js
const a =  {            "8": [{                "strategy": 123,                "id": 1,                "config": {                    "global_dag_conf": {                        "algo_v2_conf": {                            "features_to_combine": [],                            "segments": [],                            "force_performance": false,                            "min_bid": 0,                            "max_bid": 13                        }                    }                }            }],            "13": [{                "strategy": 456,                "id": 2,                "config": {                    "global_dag_conf": {                        "algo_v2_conf": {                            "ivr_measured": []                        }                    }                }            }]        };
        
let result = Object.entries(a).reduce((a, [key, arr]) => {
  return Object.assign(a, {[key]: arr.map(({id: algo_id, config}) => ({algo_id, ...config}))});
}, Object.create(null));
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```